Package 'org.springframework.http' is not getting downloaded upon upgrading Spring Boot 1.5.22 to 2.0.0
I am trying to upgrade Spring Boot version of my multi module application (built using Gradle) from version 1.5.22.RELEASE to 2.0.0.RELEASE.
Changes that I have done:
I have upgraded the version in following:
BuildScript Dependencies:

"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"

Dependencies:

"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:${springBootVersion}"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:${springBootVersion}"

Removed bootRepackage
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}

Issue I am facing:
After incorporating the above changes when I run the application, the application throws compilation errors:
 error: package org.springframework.http does not exist

Upon looking over the web, I found that this package is part of spring-boot-starter-web and it does not need any dependency in build.gradle.
Can someone help me resolve this issue?

in which class are you getting the compile error? What Spring class are you trying to import?

@JAsgarov I am getting the compilation error in {src} classes. Here is my import statement:  import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE;
